# Make a line break when identifying (number + string)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following words:

> 12"The world... 13The end 14"I have 16 years 15Kiss me

And I need to separate it like this:

> 12"The world...
>
> 13The end
>
> 14"I have 16 years
>
> 15Kiss me

To separate, I use `(number + string)` example `(123xxx)`

Any number that is concatenated with a string I need to `break` `\n` before.

I used the regex below, but it does not take into account the special symbol, and there will be several symbols in the text. And even select a number yourself

```
\d+\w+
```

[image]

I'm using this code in C#, and I just need to put a valid regex:

```
private void method()
{
    string text = "12\"The world... 13The end 14\"I have 16 years 15Kiss me";
    string ntext = Regex.Replace(text, @"\d+\w+", "\n");            
}
```

How can I make a regex that takes `(number + string)` and makes a line `break`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+(?=\d+[^\s\d])", "\n")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs%2b%28%3f%3d%5cd%2b%5b%5e%5cs%5cd%5d%29&i=12%22The+world...+13The+end+14%22I+have+16+years+15Kiss+me&r=%0d%0a).

**Details**

- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
- `(?=\d+[^\s\d])`  - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with 1+ digits and then a digit other than a digit and whitespace.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/vMIjfL):

```cs
var text = "12\"The world... 13The end 14\"I have 16 years 15Kiss me";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+(?=\d+[^\s\d])", "\n"));
```

Output:

```
12"The world...
13The end
14"I have 16 years
15Kiss me
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the example below:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(value, "[\\d]+((\\s+[^\\d]+)|(?<g2>[^\\d]+))").ToArray();
var result = string.Join("",matches.Select(x=> x.Index != 0 &&  x.Groups["g2"].Success? $"{System.Environment.NewLine}{x.Value}" : x.Value));
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't it result in 5 matches? Check [this link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cd%5d%2b%5b%5e%5cd%5d%2b&i=12%22The+world...+13The+end+14%22I+have+16+years+15Kiss+me). OP expectation is 4 matches.

Comment: Yes, there will be five matches

Comment: So, this regex is not gonna help, right? Besides, I do not see how OP can use it in the existing code, each match will be simply replaced with a line feed.

Comment: No, you only added a single optional digit/non-digit string, what if there are more? Still, this is not gonna work with the current OP code.

Comment: var matches = Regex.Matches(value, "[\\d]+((\\s+)|(?<g2>[^\\d]+))").ToArray();
 var result = string.Join("",matches.Select(x=> x.Index != 0 &&  x.Groups["g2"].Success? $"{System.Environment.NewLine}{x.Value}" : x.Value));

Comment: Now, the output of some matches is truncated, see [this proof](https://tio.run/##dVDbTgIxFHxmv@LYGLMbsHHx8iC3B2IMXhMh@sBiUrsn0KR0sae7rEG@HQusiSHxqT0z7cyckXQqSW42OSkzheEXOZy3gr8T72dao3QqM/Q/w2/RoFXy4MXg@QB4UObzABph6fgLTnMt7E25sEi094JgkX9oJUFqQQQjJBesgloFkhPOH0WmUngUyoRRUPNsrRAWCqFzhA6wuJmw0QxhmVmdcs4hPt@OaFKILxI2gJkoEOIr@EJhCeLLe@Wd5shaldJcODlD8lo@IZb8cT@HO4cGsHGSpJN6GCYJ1aPvsNeeNrvj9x0YRSzifUGuvfvUDaNfUb9irp3XJGd9Efwu8/EZa1RmfIjbWsOy04WSD0yKJRx14AxOTsADtzbLFzRm0yab8GEupS@sB8dsVfV5YwplMzNH4/gTLn3juF6V/HWbeM3gGqp7tMvT91VnGvmbVQ7DfbItsQ7Wm80P).

Comment: Sorry:) fixed [\\d]+((\\s+[^\\d]+)|(?<g2>[^\\d]+)) Yes when tested removed [^\\d]+.